# Python BeautifulSoup получить цену

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
<span class="price"><span>Цена:</span> 58&nbsp;436 <span class="currency">руб.</span></span>
```

Как получить только 58436 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
html = '<span class="price"><span>Цена:</span> 58&nbsp;436 <span class="currency">руб.</span></span>'
```

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
span = soup.find_all('span')

cost = span.text.replace('Цена: ', '').replace('\xa0', '').replace(' руб.', '')
```

```
>>> cost
58436
```